# Old links to backend still within frontend but inaccessible, cannot update them

Tags: database, ms-access

My users are working with a Access database which has been split into a frontend (DB.accdb) and a backend (DB_be.accdb). As they occasionally have to move the files, I've written a function to relink the tables upon startup.

Now, somehow they managed to break the file, I really don't know how. When the RefreshLink function is called for a table, there's always a run-time error (different ones, actually).

For example, error 3022:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again

I opened the frontend in exclusive mode, deleted the tables and manually relinked them. But a 1 is appended to their names: `someTable` --> `someTable1`. Seems like the tables already exist? Maybe they're still in a system table? As relinking would insert the linked table's names there, there would obviously be several tables with duplicate names.

I opened the connection manager, and indeed, it listed the old, wrong links among the new ones I just added.

- I cannot refresh the old links - "duplicate values" etc.
- I can refresh the new links, but of course I cannot rename the tables (removing the 1) because somehow tables with those names already exist.
- I cannot delete the old tables either, as they're not displayed in the sidebar! They don't appear even if I turn on "Show system objects" etc.
- I cannot remove the new links and then update the old links, as the connection manager button is greyed out then. Presumably Access thinks there are no tables.

And when I try to Compress & Repair the database, it uses the old links again...

How can I completely remove all traces of the previous links?

Comment: In the front-end database if you do `SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE [Type]=6` do you see a list of the linked tables (and *only* the linked tables)?

Comment: I can see the names of the new links (``someTable1`` etc.) and a few other entries ``~TMPCLPnum`` where ``num`` is a 6-digit number.

Comment: I presume the ``~TMPCLP`` records are remains of the old links? There are 10 of them, but I've got 11 tables.

Comment: Hmm. I thought you might be able to delete MSysObjects records directly but apparently we can't ("No delete permission on MSysObjects").

Comment: Have you tried creating a new empty .accdb file and then importing all of the front-end Queries, Forms, etc., into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover from what appeared to be some corruption in the old front-end database file, the solution was to

- create a new empty `.accdb` file,
- import all of the Queries, Forms, etc. from the old front-end file into the new one, and then
- create the proper table links in the new front-end file.